# Division in Java always results in zero (0)?

Tags: java, android, division

The function below gets two values from sharedpreferences, weight and height, and I use these to calculate the BMI, 
When I print the content of the values I get the values i have entered in the sharedprefs ( which is good) but then when i run a division operation on them, I always get 0 as a result..
Where is the error?

```
public int computeBMI(){
    SharedPreferences customSharedPreference = getSharedPreferences(
            "myCustomSharedPrefs", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);

    String Height = customSharedPreference.getString("heightpref", "");
    String Weight = customSharedPreference.getString("weightpref", "");

    int weight = Integer.parseInt(Weight);
    int height = Integer.parseInt(Height);
    Toast.makeText(CalculationsActivity.this, Height+" "+ Weight , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    int bmi = weight/(height*height);
    return bmi;

}
```

Comment: You're doing integer division.  Multiply by 1.0 to make it floating point.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You're doing **integer** division.

You need to cast one operand to `double`.

Answer (score 23):

You are doing an integer division, cast the values to `float` and change the datatype of the variable `bmi` to `float`.

Like this:

```
float bmi = (float)weight/(float)(height*height);
```

You should also change the return type of your method `public int computeBMI()` to `float`.

I recommend you to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4931892/why-does-the-division-of-two-integers-return-0-0-in-java) stackoverflow question.

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) you have a list of the **Primitive Data Types** in Java with its full description.

Hope it helps!

Comment: why float and not double?

Comment: depends on your needs and what kind of precision you need when storing that value @JohnnyCoder

Comment: but float might be enough for some cases

Answer (score 2):

Because `bmi` is an integer. Either declare `bmi` or `Weight, Height` as floating point numbers. When you use integers in a division, you will get integer division. When you use doubles/floats, you will get floating point division