# how to use math.pi in java

Tags: java, pi

I am having problems converting this formula `V = 4/3 π r^3`. I used `Math.PI` and `Math.pow`, but I get this error:

> ';' expected

Also, the diameter variable doesn't work. Is there an error there?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class NumericTypes    
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        double radius;
        double volume;
        double diameter;

        diameter = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("enter the diameter of a sphere.");

        radius = diameter / 2;

        volume = (4 / 3) Math.PI * Math.pow(radius, 3);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog("The radius for the sphere is "+ radius
+ "and the volume of the sphere is ");
    }
}
```

Comment: The next problem you'll encounter is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10455677/division-in-java

Answer (score 56):

You're missing the multiplication operator. Also, you want to do `4/3` in floating point, not integer math.

```
volume = (4.0 / 3) * Math.PI * Math.pow(radius, 3);
           ^^      ^
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is usage of `Math.PI` to find circumference of circle and Area
First we take Radius as a string in Message Box and convert it into integer

```
public class circle {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here

        String rad;

        float radius,area,circum;

       rad = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the Radius of circle:");

        radius = Integer.parseInt(rad);
        area = (float) (Math.PI*radius*radius);
        circum = (float) (2*Math.PI*radius);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Area: " + area,"AREA",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "circumference: " + circum, "Circumfernce",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Replace

```
volume = (4 / 3) Math.PI * Math.pow(radius, 3);
```

With:

```
volume = (4 * Math.PI * Math.pow(radius, 3)) / 3;
```

Comment: Perhaps add some explanation on what you did here?

Comment: @orhtej2 (4 / 3) returns 1. So he multiplies with 4 a float in order to get a float and then divides with 3, in order to get a float result.

Answer (score 1):

Your diameter variable won't work because you're trying to store a String into a variable that will only accept a double. In order for it to work you will need to parse it

Ex:

```java
diameter = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("enter the diameter of a sphere.");
```