# Java Arithmetic division

Tags: java, integer-arithmetic

```
public class test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
   int total = 2;
   int rn = 1;
   double rnp = (rn / total) * 100;
   System.out.println(rnp);
 }
}
```

Why it prints 0.0 instead of 50.0?

[https://www.google.com/search?q=100*(1%2F2)&aq=f&oq=100*(1%2F2)](https://www.google.com/search?q=100%2a%281/2%29&aq=f&oq=100%2a%281/2%29)

Comment: Because `1/2` is 0 in integer division.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Division in Java always results in zero (0)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10455677/division-in-java-always-results-in-zero-0)

Comment: Also could be considered duplicate of [C programming division](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8906722/c-programming-division) considering the answer is the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The division occurs in integer space with no notion of fractions, you need something like

```
double rnp = (rn / (double) total) * 100
```

Answer (score 2):

You are invoking integer division here

```
(rn / total)
```

Integer division rounds towards zero.

Try this instead:

```
double rnp = ((double)rn / total) * 100;
```

Comment: Look closer. The cast is before the division.

Comment: Turns out your eye for observation is better than mine :)

Answer (score 0):

In java, and most other programming languages, when you divide two integers, the result is also an integer. The remainder is discarded. Thus, `1 / 2` returns `0`. If you want a `float` or `double` value returned, you need to do something like `1 * 1.0 / 2`, which will return `0.5`. Multiplying or dividing an integer by a double or float converts it to that format.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class test
{
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
   int total = 2;
   int rn = 1;
   double rnp = (rn / (float)total) * 100;
   System.out.println(rnp);
 }
}
```