# Calculation always results in zero

Tags: java

I have the following java code

```
long x=25782

float y=x/1000000000
```

Instead of y being equal to 0.000025782 as I would expect, it is equals 0.0

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10455677/division-in-java-always-results-in-zero-0?rq=1

Comment: How did you get 396 rep on this site if you're asking questions that can be answered with 3 seconds of googling?

Comment: @PaulTomblin 1) Uncalled for scathing remark; 2) You know as well as everybody else games can be *gamed* and in many respects StackOverflow fails to promote value especially when a lot of marginally good answers to bad questions gets you further than one good answer to a very good question... in the same amount of time.

Comment: @PaulTomblin I'm not saying (by any means) that you should overlook the fact that this is a bad (duplicate) question. By all means, down-vote and vote-to-close to your heart' desire, that's what the buttons are there for. Just don't make the entire experience more unpleasant that it needs to be.

Comment: @PaulTomblin perhaps if points gained from closed questions will would be retracted, people wouldn't struggle to answer an obvious duplicate question by googling for it and finding it... where else... on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an integer division, which will round to the right of the decimal point, as integer division gives integer result.

You should cast `x` to float.

Try:

```
float y=(float)x/1000000000;
```

Comment: I believe you were thinking of "cast" not "convert" =)

Comment: Thanks. I feel a bit dumb now as I should have spotted that. I think a combination of a bad day and using java has had a profound affect on me......

Answer (score 5):

You're dividing by an `long` type, so it will round down to `0`.

Use this instead:

```
float y=x/1000000000.0;
```

Comment: I would also recomment using a double for y if he wants a better precision

Comment: Yup. And they can also put `f` at the end too, instead of the `.0`.

Answer (score 1):

## Integer division gives an integer result

This is integer division; in integer division the answer is always an integer (by truncating the non integer part, not be rounding). Which you are then casting to a float.

The easiest solution is to include at least 1 float. So

```
long x=25782

float y=x/1000000000f //(or 1000000000.0)
```

## What you are effectively doing

```
float y=x/1000000000;
float y=(float)(int)(x/1000000000);
float y=(float)(int)(25782/1000000000);
float y=(float)0;
float y=0.0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Int and long division always result in int and long.

at least operand in your calculation needs to be a float or double