# How to use Math.PI and Math.pow

Tags: java, math, pow

I am doing an assignment for my first JAVA programming. So far it has been going well but I am stuck at the last part with using math functions.

```
double radius;
double diameter;
double volume;

System.out.print("Enter a diameter of a sphere: ");
diameter = keyboard.nextDouble();
radius = diameter / 2;
volume = (4 / 3) * Math.PI * Math.pow(radius, 3.0);
System.out.print("Volume of the sphere is " + volume + ".");
```

I am trying to use the formula for finding a volume of a sphere using diameter input variable. But I keep getting just the PI as an output.

This is what I am supposed to do.

1. Add a line that prompts the user to enter the diameter of a sphere.
2. Read in and store the number into a variable called diameter (you will need to
   declare any variables that you use).
3. The diameter is twice as long as the radius, so calculate and store the radius in an
   appropriately named variable.
4. The formula for the volume of a sphere is
   V = 4/3 * PI * radius^3
   Convert the formula to Java and add a line which calculates and stores the value
   of volume in an appropriately named variable. Use Math.PI for PI and Math.pow
   to cube the radius.
5. Print your results to the screen with an appropriate message.

What am I doing wrong ? Also how do I make it so the volume displays with E notation?

Comment: `(4 / 3)` evaluates to **zero** since Java will be using `Integer Arithmetic`.

Comment: Use this formula for the volume instead of yours `4 * Math.PI * Math.pow(radius, 3.0) / 3` (refer to @PM77-1 to see why it is necessary).

Comment: @PM77-1 You should post a more detailed answer for him to understand

Comment: See [Division in Java always results in zero (0)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10455677/division-in-java-always-results-in-zero-0).

Comment: I see that numerator requires it to be decimal. Is it necessary for every time I use fraction in java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be getting an incorrect ans because of 4/3 in Integer Math give 1 and not 1.33 Try changing you code to what is give below. I tried and worked fine for me.

```
radius = diameter / 2.0d;
volume = (4.0d / 3.0d) * Math.PI * Math.pow(radius, 3);
```

Comment: This is a good (and correct) comment but not an answer.

Comment: @PM77-1, good point. I am still new to some of the etiquette at stack. I guess that post would have been enough for me to go off of as an answer :)

Comment: You do not need `d`. It will be `double` by default.