# 2 / 4 = 0.0 in java?

Tags: java, math, integer, double

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does the division of two integers return 0.0 in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4931892/why-does-the-division-of-two-integers-return-0-0-in-java)

I have some very confusing problem..
I want to calculate some stuff and after some debugging I saw that java calculates this arithmetic: **2 / 4 = 0.0** But it should be 0.5

2 & 4 are stored in integer variables
the result is stored in a double-type.

Did I miss something clearly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is because of integer division (Integer division rounds toward 0). Cast one of the operand to double type.

Example:

`double temp = (double)2/4`

will give you correct results.

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
myDouble = (double) integerWhoseValueIs2 / integerWhoseValueIs4
```

The fact you store it in a double doesn't change the fact that the division of two integers makes an integer. When you store it, it's too late.

From the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.2) :

> Integer division rounds toward 0. That is, the quotient produced for
>   operands n and d that are integers after binary numeric promotion
>   (§5.6.2) is an integer value q whose magnitude is as large as possible
>   while satisfying |d · q| ≤ |n|.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not write a cast to `double`, the result is always an `int`.

`double a = (double) 2/4;`