# Returning Double from compound division of Integers

Tags: java, division

I am trying to return a `double` from this `int` division. I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4931892/why-does-the-division-of-two-integers-return-0-0-in-java) but I cant seem to make it work for this particular case:

```
yComponent +=
        ((Math.min(i.getObservedIndividuals(), ii.getObservedIndividuals()))/
        Math.max(i.getObservedIndividuals(), ii.getObservedIndividuals())*
        i.getObservedIndividuals())/
        (parent.getShareableSpecies()*
        match.getTotalObservedIndividuals());
```

`yComponent` is a `double` and everything else is `int`.

Comment: It doesn't matter what `yComponent` is, it's not part of the quotient.  What is the type of `i.getObservedIndividuals()`?

Comment: You probably need a cast to double in there. It's probably doing integer division but I didn't read it close.

Comment: @shawnt00 I know this is integer division and its returning 0.00. I tried some casting but nothing. It is still returning 0.00 somehow.

Comment: Why all the extra parentheses when everything's division/multiplication? They make things hard to read.

Comment: @SteveK It makes it easier to me to show what belongs where. I've just always done it this way (specially when its a long formula).

Comment: @Alexander An easier way to make it easier to read is to introduce named identifiers for your mid calculations ie: `int minIndividuals = Math.min(i.getObservedIndividuals(), ii.getObservedIndividuals()); int maxIndividuals = Math.max(i.getObservedIndividuals(), ii.getObservedIndividuals()); int percentPopulation = minIndividuals / maxIndividuals * i.getObservedIndividuals();` etc. Yes, it's more lines of code, but it's a hell of a lot easier to understand what the intention of your calculation is, and to make sure the steps are correct.

Comment: Might help if you gave us actual numbers to work with or at least the value you expect to get.

Comment: Also, @shawnt00 is correct; if the numbers are too close, when the integer division happens, if the number rounds down to less than 0.5, it will return 0. You need to use floats when doing division.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
yComponent +=
    ((Math.min(i.getObservedIndividuals(), ii.getObservedIndividuals())) /
    (double) Math.max(i.getObservedIndividuals(), ii.getObservedIndividuals())*
    i.getObservedIndividuals()) /
    (double) (parent.getShareableSpecies()*
    match.getTotalObservedIndividuals());
```

A division won't use the "float processor" (arithmetic processor) if you don't cast at least one operand as a double or float. Which means that `3 / 2 = 1` for a CPU, but `3 / 2f = 1.5f`