# Percentage Calculation giving me zero in Java

Tags: java, typecasting-operator

my code: 
`long totalVolume = sellVolume + buyVolume;
 float sellPercent = (float)(sellVolume / totalVolume);
 float buyPercent = (float)(buyVolume / totalVolume);`

All the variable are long in the first line of code, and then I am trying to calculate the Percentage of it.... but java returns me zero only ...
why is it so - Am i doing something wrong in typecasting

Comment: The `float` cast is too late.  The division is being performed in `long`.

Comment: You are explicitly only casting after you have performed the integer division, don't do that.  Also don't use `float` as it imprecise, at least using `double` or `BigDecimal`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does the division of two integers return 0.0 in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4931892/why-does-the-division-of-two-integers-return-0-0-in-java)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should cast one of the operands to `float` before performing the division in order to perform floating point division (instead of long division).

```
float sellPercent = (float)sellVolume / totalVolume;
float buyPercent = (float)buyVolume / totalVolume;
```