# Why is the value I'm getting different for 2 similar programs below even though i only changed the type for the method's value

Tags: java, methods

Code 1:
*Class 1*

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;

public class testing2 {
int balance;

void addInterest(int rate) {
    balance += balance*(rate/100);

}

void display() {
    NumberFormat currency = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();

    System.out.print ("The balance is ");
    System.out.print(currency.format(balance));

    }
}
```

*Class 2*

```
import java.util.Random;

public class testing {

public static void main (String args[]) {

    testing2 aTesting = new testing2();
    Random Myrandom = new Random();

    aTesting.balance = Myrandom.nextInt(501);
    int rate2 = 5;

    System.out.println("Current balance: " + aTesting.balance);
    System.out.println("Current rate: " + rate2);

    aTesting.addInterest(rate2);

    aTesting.display();

    System.out.println();
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

Current balance: 327
Current rate: 5
The balance is MYR327.00

Code 2:
*Class 1*

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;

public class testing2 {
double balance;

void addInterest(double rate) {
    balance += balance*(rate/100);

}

void display() {
    NumberFormat currency = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();

    System.out.print ("The balance is ");
    System.out.print(currency.format(balance));

    }
}
```

*Class 2*

```
import java.util.Random;

public class testing {

public static void main (String args[]) {

    testing2 aTesting = new testing2();
    Random Myrandom = new Random();

    aTesting.balance = Myrandom.nextInt(501);
    double rate2 = 5;

    System.out.println("Current balance: " + aTesting.balance);
    System.out.println("Current rate: " + rate2);

    aTesting.addInterest(rate2);

    aTesting.display();

    System.out.println();
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

Current balance: 170.0
Current rate: 5.0
The balance is MYR178.50

CONCLUSION: The first program does not change the final value of the balance whilst the 2nd program does. What is the reason for this? I only changed the type of the variable from int to double and nothing more.

Comment: Why don't you make a title, then put the question in the body?

Comment: I really don't understand why you paste an identical class twice. You could just write the line you changed.

Comment: The problem is entirely in the expression `rate/100`. When `rate` is an `int` with value 5, the value of that expression is 0 as the division is being performed in integer arithmetic.

Comment: Whilst *you* may consider it "only", don't you feel that there may be differences between something that can have decimals and something that can't?

Comment: @JonSkeet thanks a bunch. I only realized it after you mentioned.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does the division of two integers return 0.0 in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4931892/why-does-the-division-of-two-integers-return-0-0-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

In first case you're doing

```
int balance = 327;
int rate = 5;
balance += balance * (rate / 100);
```

When you do division on `int` result is also int, so result of division `rate / 100` is `(int)rate / 100` what gives`(int)0.05` which is `0`. What gives `balance += balance * 0` that's why balance hasn't changed in first program.

When you change your variables and parameters to `double` there is no truncating values so all calculations go as you expect.

Answer (score 1):

> The first program does not change the final value of the balance
>   whilst the 2nd program does. What is the reason for this ?

**It is all about double vs integer arithmetic.**

```
void addInterest(double rate) {
   balance += balance*(rate/100);
}
```

In the second program, when you call `addInterest(double rate)`, the value of `rate` passed from `main()` will be type-casted into `double` variable (which is the type defined by `addInterest` method signature) and then `balance*(rate/100)` will be calculated like below:

When `rate` is `double`:
**rate/100 = 5/100 = 0.05**

But, when `rate` is `integer`:
**rate/100 = 5/100 = 0 (intgers strip all decimals)**

Answer (score 1):

If you declare two variables as integers and divide them:

```
int a = 4;
int b = 5;
System.out.println(a / b);
```

You'll *not* get 0.8.

In Java, an integer divided by an integer is *always an integer* and since the mathematical result, 0.8 is not an integer, it is rounded down to get 0. If you want to get the result 0.8, you need to make either a or b a double.

In Code 1, your `addInterest` method gets a argument value of `5` and this happens:

```
balance += balance*(rate/100);
```

Since `rate` and `100` are all integers, the result must be an integer. Therefore, the mathematical result 0.05 is rounded down to get 0. And as we all know, anything that is multiplied by 0 is 0. As a result, after the right side is evaluated, the assignment statement looks like this:

```
balance += 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because in your first you have:

int rate2 = 5;

and in your second you have:

double rate2 = 5;

You should be using double when dealing with currency type values.

Comment: That's exactly the change stated in the question. Without any explanation of why, even with the upvote, is this any use?

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic problem for beginners. I'm surprised I can't find a really good explanation. This one is a bit helpful:

[Why is the result of 1/3 == 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685450/why-is-the-result-of-1-3-0)

In Java how an operation like division (`/`) is performed depends on the types of the operands. In `a/b` `a` and `b` are the operands. If you divide integer by integer it performs integer division. The means taking the whole number part and discarding the remainder. In that method `(56/100) == 0` but `(156/100) == 1` no rounding.

To force floating point arithmetic make sure one of the operands is `double` for example try:

```
void addInterest(int rate) {
    balance += balance*(rate/100.0);
}
```

The compiler will interpret `100.0` as `double` then perform the calculation in floating point arithmetic (probably what you were expecting) and then take the integer value to add to `balance`.

Footnote 1: Never use `double` for currency values. Use `java.math.BigDecimal` there a number of rounding oddities in `double` arithmetic that cause problems in financial calculations. `double` can't represent `0.01` precisely and accumulating rounding errors inevitably cause some confusion when `(0.01+0.01+0.01+0.01+0.01+0.01)!=0.06` for example.
You can fudge round it with tolerances but in financial systems of any real size you will eventually go outside it.

Footnote 2: Why does Java work like this? Integer arithmetic is useful for many algorithms and in loops performing millions of increments will never 'drift off' like we can see happening after just 6 operations above!